'.Net location: not found' error in Linux
I have installed .Net 8 SDK before in Raspbian Lite of Raspberry Pi.
Here is the output of dotnet --info:
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.303
 Commit:            29ab8e3268
 Workload version:  8.0.300-manifests.c915c39d
 MSBuild version:   17.10.4+10fbfbf2e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  12
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-arm64
 Base Path:   /home/admin/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/

.NET workloads installed:
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
  Version:      8.0.7
  Architecture: arm64
  Commit:       2aade6beb0

.NET SDKs installed:
  8.0.303 [/home/admin/.dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.7 [/home/admin/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.7 [/home/admin/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/home/admin/.dotnet]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

However, when I run a .Net program with Framework-dependent, it reports this error:
admin@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ./Sample/Sample --drm
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /home/admin/Sample/Sample
Architecture: arm64
App host version: 8.0.7
.NET location: Not found

Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=arm64&rid=linux-arm64&os=debian.12&apphost_version=8.0.7

And here is the location of the .net SDK:


What's more, I can run the same program with deploy Self-Contained successfully.
What's wrong with it?

sudo ./Sample/Sample --drm is not the same as .Sample/Sample --drm - perhaps the best thing is first to try running your application without sudo . Why do you need sudo to run this app? Also might want to compare dotnet --info and sudo dotnet --info or env vs sudo env

FWIW /home/admin/.dotnet does not appear to be a standard location for dotnet ... more reasons why a program run with sudo might not find it.

@topsail it reports this error:-bash: .Sample/Sample: No such file or directory

@topsail I installed the .net sdk using the script at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment. The installation location was automatically selected by the script and I did not change it manually.

@topsail well, it works without sudo by ./Sample/Sample --drm

@topsail But why does it work without sudo but not with it? In my opinion, the function of sudo is to use administrator privileges to execute a command, which logically should be higher than without sudo privileges.

Why would it not work without sudo ... the short answer is that in linux the su user is historically an actual, different user. Using sudo is more like "running as the su user" than "giving the current user elevated rights". You can also think of this as starting a shell as the su user to run the program (which may or may not be technically accurate) - that can effect the environment variables available to the shell which may not be the same.
